# Restart indesign ruler at every page

Tags: adobe-indesign

In indesign 5, I have created several A4 pages after another. However the ruler stretches over the three pages, see picture below, and I would rather see them "restarting" at every page, i.e. ever page should have its own ruler. Is this possible?

[image: ID5 screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if what you're asking is possible, but you can try going to Edit> Preferences> Units & Increments and changing the origin from Spread to Page. If not then.. I dunno :)

Comment: No you where correct. This works a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Well then, you're welcome :)